# PHP - Array replacing same values and showing one record less

Tags: php, arrays

`$hours_effort_result` output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14453
                    [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 1
                    [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 20
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14559
                    [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 2
                    [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 50
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14559
                    [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 2
                    [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 150
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14611
                    [EMPLOYEE_NAME] => User 3
                    [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 60
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [MONTH_YEAR] => JUL-2015
                )
```

**Array manipulation**

```
$user_array = Array();
foreach ($hours_effort_result as $key => $data) {

                if (!empty($data)) {

                    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {

                        if ('JUL-2015' == $month) {


                            $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['EMPLOYEEID'] = $val['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
                            $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['SITE_STATUS'] = $val['SITE_STATUS'];
                            $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['PROJECTED_HOURS'] = $val['PROJECTED_HOURS'];

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

`$user_array` output

```
Array
(
    [User 1] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14453
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 20
                )

        )

    [User 2] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14559
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 150
                )

        )

    [User 3] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14611
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 60
                )

        )
```

Here `$user_array` has two records for `User 2` but showing only `one` record. Value is stored at same `key` and so it overrides and display the last value for that `key`

How do I avoid this and show same number of records coming from `$hours_effort_result` ?

**Desired Final Output**

```
Array
(
    [User 1] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14453
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 20
                )

        )

    [User 2] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14559
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 50
                )

        )


    [User 2] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14559
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 150
                )

        )

    [User 3] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14611
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 60
                )

        )
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. How is the final array suppose to look like?

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen, pls see my Edit with desired output

Comment: An array can't hold two identical keys.

Comment: I can't believe how many answer this question is getting before such important information is brought up.

Comment: @JoachimMartinsen, thats true. But what if those identical keys contains different set of information as you can see `PROJECTED_HOURS` are different for User 2

Comment: The value doesn't matter. If the key is identical it just gets overwritten.

Comment: So, if allowing duplicate keys is not possible, what could be the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PHP code and try agian :-

```
$final_array = Array();
foreach ($hours_effort_result as $key => $data)
{
    if (!empty($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $val)
        {
            if ('JUL-2015' == $month)
            {
                $user_array = Array();

                $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['EMPLOYEEID'] = $val['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
                $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['SITE_STATUS'] = $val['SITE_STATUS'];
                $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['PROJECTED_HOURS'] = $val['PROJECTED_HOURS'];

                array_push($final_array, $user_array);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now print $final_array and you got the answer you want.

Comment: `$final_array` outputs data but again calls for another loop as its adding index `[0], [1]`. Need data like `[User 2] => Array ( [JUL-2015] => Array ( [EMPLOYEEID] => 14453 [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 50 ) ) [User 2] => Array ( [JUL-2015] => Array ( [EMPLOYEEID] => 14453 [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 50 ) )`

Comment: it is not possible to use same key to store data you have to get some unique item in array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using something else as the key and it's not unique. The employee name is the same for the records 1 and 2 in the original array.

Simply use a unique key for the second array.

Comment: Considering key `$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']` also gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

The two records of User2 are same. And according to the meaning or the attributes. I think it's duplicated and should be treated as data error.

Answer (score -1):

Instead

```
$user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['EMPLOYEEID'] = $val['ACTUAL_HOURS'];
$user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['SITE_STATUS'] = $val['SITE_STATUS'];
$user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month]['PROJECTED_HOURS'] = $val['PROJECTED_HOURS'];
```

use

```
if (!isset($user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month])) {
     $user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month] = array();
}
$user_array[$val['EMPLOYEE_NAME']][$month][] = array(
     'EMPLOYEEID' => $val['ACTUAL_HOURS'],
     'SITE_STATUS' => $val['SITE_STATUS'],
     'PROJECTED_HOURS' => $val['PROJECTED_HOURS']
);
```

Comment: The above code changes current array format. How to process data so that it outputs something like `[User 2] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14453
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 50
                )

        )

  
[User 2] => Array
        (
            [JUL-2015] => Array
                (
                    [EMPLOYEEID] => 14453
                    [SITE_STATUS] => Offshore
                    [PROJECTED_HOURS] => 50
                )

        )
`